# AWS Lambda: "No module named 'numexpr.interpreter'" error with asammdf package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy a Python Lambda function on AWS that utilizes the asammdf package. The function works perfectly on my local machine, but when I deploy it to AWS Lambda, I encounter the following error:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named
> 'numexpr.interpreter'

**What I've tried:**

1. I've created a virtual environment on my Windows machine and
   installed the necessary packages, including asammdf.
2. Packaged the function along with its dependencies from the
   site-packages directory of my virtual environment.
3. Checked for potential library conflicts and made sure that the
   numexpr dependency was included in the package.

Despite these efforts, I'm still facing this import error. The asammdf package seems to rely on numexpr, but I can't seem to get it to work on Lambda.

Can anyone help?